# How to override default HTML Helper of Cakephp?

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp, helper

I’m given theme by designer and I’m assigned to integrate it with the product. Since the product size in term of source code is massive, I have to modify almost all the views and layouts. Moreover, the development of the product will go for next 2 years which is plan.

I’m trying to override HTML Helper class of Cakephp so that it will change all the default classes of css. Due to this strategy developers won’t have to utilize more effort to for views and it will ease future development.
Right now

```
echo $this->Form->input('username');
```

Generates

```
<div class="input text required">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" required="required" maxlength="30" name="data[User][username]">
</div>
```

And I want this by overriding HTML Helper.

```
<div class="form-group has-error">           
    <label for="inputError" class="control-label">Input with error</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" name=" data[User][username]" required="required">                           
</div>
```

This is one example of textbox. Please assists, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't override it. But you can build another helper **extending** the FormHelper.

I did that once to turning my form creation proccess more simple to do with the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) css built-in classes.

```
class BFormHelper extends FormHelper {

    public function label($fieldName = null, $text = null, $options = array()){
        $myOptions = array('class' => 'control-label');
        return parent::label($fieldName, $text, array_merge($options, $myOptions));
    }
}
```

That way we encapsulate the use of the CSS class `control-label`, and in case of need to change it, we only need to do it in one place.

Then, on the view you simply do:

```
<?= $this->BForm->label('somefield', 'Some bootstrap field') ?>
```

The CakePHP version I did this was 1.3.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to extend the `FormHelper`. The cake way is to extend the `AppHelper` and inside that to define the `$helpers` array containing any of the core helpers.

Comment: He asked for overriding cake's default behavior. So here it is.

Comment: Extending the helper is the correct way. What this answer is missing is that you can alias the helper and always use the "$this->Form" in your views. Aliasing a helper is done in AppController like this `public $helpers = ['Form' => ['className' => 'BForm']]`

Comment: @AlmirFilho I'm not arguing about if you are extending the `FormHelper`. What I'm saying is that it's better to create a new helper extending the `AppHelper` and inside that, use as many times as you like the `FormHelper`. I believe, from my experience, that all the functionality of your helpers, models, controllers in your application **must** be an extension of the core. This means that you always extend the `AppModel` and not some other model, the `AppController` etc... The same rule applies to helpers also.

Comment: Copying from the book http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers: Helpers must extend either AppHelper or Helper or implement all the callbacks in the Helper API.

Comment: @CrisSawfish I agree with you. However, considering that it's not the universal truth, using extension may be more appropriate in some cases, instead of composition. The programmer may be able to decide whatever he wants to do and how. =)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like you are using the bootstrap css framework. I recommend you to use this plugin:

http://slywalker.github.io/cakephp-plugin-boost_cake/

Comment: it is not actually botostrap. i gave example of it.

Comment: Check the plugin examples, it shows the usual steps you need to overriding the helpers and adding your won markup

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate the code above, you can always use the core `FormHelper` like that:

```
<?php
echo "<div class=\"form-group has-error\">."
    . $this->Form->label('username', '<your-text-goes-here>', array('class' => 'control-label'))
    . $this->Form->input('username', array('class' => 'form-control', 'label' => false, 'div' => false))
    . "</div>\n";
?>
```

The core `FormHelper` can be fully customized to meet your needs. But this way implies that your will have to give extra effort in your views. Read the corresponding section in [cakebook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) on how to customize the core `FormHelper`.

If you want to minimize the code in your views, you can create a custom form helper
like the sample given below.

```
<?php
class CustomformHelper extends AppHelper {
    public $helpers = array('Form');

    public function customInput(<your-options-goes-here>) {
        /* Write your custom code for the specific type of input
         * you want to create. */
    }
};
?>
```

In your custom helper, you can introduce any other of the core helpers, by defining
the `$helpers` array, like you did it in your controllers.

All the core helpers you defined in `$helpers` array are available from withing `$this`.
For example if you want to call the `FormHelper::input()` method, from within your custom method, you can use the following code: `$this->Form->input(...)`

See also the section on [how to create custom helpers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers) in the cakebook

Comment: You are advising to change core FormHelper ?

Comment: This is actually your decision... I myself, almost never write custom helpers. I prefer to use the core ones and write a few more lines of code in my views.

Comment: @MoyedAnsari I thought your question a littble bit more. I believe that if the modifications you have to do can be limited compacted to a few methods in a custom helper, then yes it's always easier to do that, with the expence of making the application a bit more heavier (loading one more class). But you have to make sure that your helper keeps DRY.

Comment: if i make new custom helper then i have to modify previously written elements. it is again headache

Comment: @MoyedAnsari no matter what you do, you will have to make modifications to your views and elements.